# Delete a node from a tree and return the resulting forest

Tags: haskell, tree

I'm coming from a Java background and want to learn some Haskell. Bit stuck at the moment, though.

What I want to do is: I have a list of trees where each node has a unique identifier across all trees in the list. Now I want to delete one node out of one of these trees and return the new trees as well as the unchanged trees.

Deleting a node should:

- make all children of said node become root of new trees
- delete parent nodes of the deleted node up to and including the root node and do the above for all deleted nodes as well

Imagine the following trees:

[image]

When I delete node '2' I want the result to be the following trees:

[image]

Each node in a tree consists of the identifier and a list of child trees.
Here is what I have so far, however it's obviously not working and I'm a bit lost on how I can solve this with Haskell:

```
import Data.Tree
data CustomNode = CustomNode { identifier :: Int } deriving (Ord,Eq,Show,Read)
type CustomTree = Tree CustomNode

myTree0 = t0
    where
        leaf i = Node CustomNode{identifier = i} []
        t0 = Node CustomNode{identifier = 0} [t1]
        t1 = Node CustomNode{identifier = 1} [t2, t5]
        t2 = Node CustomNode{identifier = 2} [leaf 3, leaf 4] 
        t5 = Node CustomNode{identifier = 5} [leaf 6]

myTree1 = t0
    where
        leaf i = Node CustomNode{identifier = i} []
        t0 = Node CustomNode{identifier = 7} [leaf 8]

deleteNode :: Int -> [CustomTree] -> [CustomTree]
deleteNode _ [] = []
deleteNode n (x:xs) = if isNodeInTree n x then deleteNodeFromTree n x ++ xs else deleteNode n xs
--below is the fixed line as per the answer below
--deleteNode n (x:xs) = if isNodeInTree n x then deleteNodeFromTree n x ++ xs else x : deleteNode n xs

deleteNodeFromTree :: Int -> CustomTree -> [CustomTree]
deleteNodeFromTree n (Node c xs) = if identifier c == n then [] else deleteNode n xs
--below is the fixed line as per the answer below
--deleteNodeFromTree n (Node c xs) = if identifier c == n then xs else deleteNode n xs

isNodeInTree :: Int -> CustomTree -> Bool
isNodeInTree n (Node c xs) = if identifier c == n then True else isNodeInForest n xs

isNodeInForest :: Int -> [CustomTree] -> Bool
isNodeInForest n [] = False
isNodeInForest n (x:xs) = if isNodeInTree n x then True else isNodeInForest n xs
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Yes. Sorry, I forgot to add the import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've made a reasonable start here.

I'm presuming you hope for `deleteNode` to take a forest and return that same forest, but with the specified node removed. In that case,

```
if isNodeInTree n x then ... else deleteNode n xs
```

you just threw `x` away. You probably didn't mean to do that.

```
... else x : deleteNode n xs
```

would keep that tree in the forest, which is probably what you intended.

Also, in `deleteNodeFromTree`:

```
if identifier c == n then [] ...
```

Perhaps you wanted to return all the children of the node at this point? (So they all become root nodes.)

Those are the only things that stand out to me. See where that takes you...

Comment: Amazing, those 2 things were everything that was missing! I thought it would be way more work! Thanks very much, Haskell is actually quite awesome :)

Comment: @Marco Happy Hasklling. ;-)